# How to find out a Query that is being used by a page

Tags: php, mysql, moodle

I have a page where you can select a couple of drop-down lists to choose options on how to display the website log, so different searches on the log can be made, however the results are way too long to be exported to a csv file by the website (Moodle in this question - PHP).

So what I'm thinking is if I can somehow display the exact query it was used on the "search" I could run it straight on the database using myPhpAdmin and export the results from there.

Comment: You are going to have to provide some of the code that builds the query...

Comment: Do you have access to the MySQL server? Can you enable query audit logging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your database server isn't that busy, instead of hacking around in your application and trying to get it to display the queries before they're executed, which can be tricky, you could always turn on the [general query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/query-log.html) and look for the query in question.

```
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';
```

Be sure to turn off the query logger once you're done. Logging every query is a great way to crash your database because it *will* run out of disk space eventually.

Comment: Unfortunately i only have access to phpmyadmin not the full server... Is there some type of debug code I can run that will display the query string on the page, or even on a alert box?

Comment: If you can find the point of execution within your app, usually it's not too hard to shim in some logging code just before the query is executed.